# Why isn't my last else statement printing "invalid characters" for anything besides numbers?

Tags: c, validation, if-statement, input, user-input

It should be accepting digit as scores. The program will continue to accept values until a negative number is input. (solved)

I just need to know how to **display invalid if its anything besides numbers are input**. I tried using else statement for displaying "invalid" but it doesn't work. **I'm new to c programming**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int numericScore=0,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,f=0;
      
    while(numericScore>-1) //while loop
    {
        printf("What is the score?\n");
        scanf("%d",&numericScore);
      
        if (numericScore >100)
            break;
        
        if (numericScore >=90 && numericScore <=100)
        {
            a++; //increment
            printf("grade is A \n" );
        } 
    
        else if (numericScore>=80 )
        {
            b++; //increment
            printf("grade is B \n");
        }
    
        else if (numericScore >=70)
        {
            c++; //increment
            printf("grade is C\n");
        }
    
        else if (numericScore >=60)
        { 
            d++; //increment
            printf("grade is D\n");
        }
    
        else if (numericScore>=0 && numericScore <60  )
        {
            f++; //increment
            printf("grade is F\n");
        }
    
        else if (numericScore <0)
            break;
    
        else
        {
            printf("invalid");
        }
          
    }
    printf("%d A's\n",a); // number of letter grade
    printf("%d B's\n",b);
    printf("%d C's\n",c);
    printf("%d D's\n",d);
    printf("%d F's\n",f);
      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` will only read an integer. You can't use that to input something else and check if it's a number.

Comment: you can make use of the fact that scanf( ) has a return value that can be tested for success. If an integer is not entered, it will fail. following will help:
`#include <stdio.h>`     
`int main()`      
`{`

 `int number; `

 `printf("Enter a number:");`

 `if(scanf("%d",&number)){`

  `printf("\n %d is integer",number);`

  `/Write your other logic here for your program`

 `}`

 `else{`

  `printf("invalid");`

 `}`

 `return 0;`

`}`

Sorry not able to format the code properly in comment. :(